# implicitly convert higher order type

Tags: scala

I'm a scala newbie...so assume ignorance.

so if I look at the definition of <:<

`sealed abstract class <:<[-From, +To] extends (From => To)
implicit def conforms[A]: A <:< A = new (A <:< A) {def apply(x: A) = x}`

and this is used to define evidence that a type A is a subtype of B.

A <: B

...but what if I want to have evidence that;

forall T. A[T] <: B[T]

?

ok....so I try to follow the same recipe

```
abstract class Foo[-A[_],+B[_]] { def apply[C](x : A[C]) : B[C] }

implicit def conforms[A[_]] : Foo[A,A] = new Foo[A,A] { def apply[C](x : A[C]) : A[C] = x }
```

I can use this constraint an manually apply the conversion, but I can't get the compiler to implicitly "apply" it. (because it doesn't extend A=>B?)

so for example if I define;

```
  abstract class FooInt[-A[_],+B[_]] extends (A[Int] => B[Int])

implicit def conformsInt[A[Int]] : FooInt[A,A] = new FooInt[A,A] { def apply(x : A[Int]) : A[Int] = x }
```

then the compiler will automatically apply the conversion to values of type A[Int]

I just want to generalise this to A[T]

thoughts?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. You will have to add a use case for `Foo` to understand where you want to go with this. Note that F# is HM-typed whereas Scala is nominally typed. I guess the confusion arises from there.

Comment: hmmm...let me have a think, the problem with actually giving the full example is it all gets hidden in the mud

Comment: the fundamental problem is that implicit conversions assume we implement "A=>B"

Answer (score 0):

`sealed abstract class <:<` - this tells you that you cannot construct "new evidence". You have to rely on the compiler confirming that two existing types do meet the existing evidence. This should work for all types already, if not, you try to proof something that is wrong.

You state you want proof that `A[T] <: B[T] forAll { type T }`. This will depend on the variance of A's and B's type parameter. If you want to ignore that parameter, you can only ask for evidence `A[_] <:< B[_]`. E.g.

```
trait Animal; trait Cat extends Animal

trait Foo[A]
trait Bar[A] extends Foo[A]

implicitly[Bar[Cat]    <:< Foo[Cat]]     // ok, A is fixed
implicitly[Bar[Cat]    <:< Foo[Animal]]  // not possible
implicitly[Bar[Animal] <:< Foo[Cat]]     // not possible
implicitly[Bar[_]      <:< Foo[_]]       // ok, we forget about A
```

If you had variances, you could preserve A:

```
trait Breeds[+A]  // covariant, can "produce" A
trait Feeds [-A]  // contravariant, can "consume" A
class Baz[A] extends Breeds[A] with Feeds[A]

implicitly[Baz[Cat]    <:< Feeds[Animal]]  // nope
implicitly[Baz[Animal] <:< Feeds[Cat]]     // ok
implicitly[Baz[Cat]    <:< Breeds[Animal]] // ok
implicitly[Baz[Animal] <:< Breeds[Cat]]    // nope
```

Comment: is this valid scala? "A[T] <: B[T] forAll { type T }"

Comment: @user2088029 No, it is just a way to talk about a universally quantified `T`.

Comment: @user2088029 No, if you mean that I can define a type like that. But it is equivalent to `A[_] <: B[_]`, in that the type parameter T is ["existential"](https://www.cakesolutions.net/teamblogs/existential-types-in-scala).

Comment: ok, lets forget about "-" and "+" they are actually irrelevant because I want to constrain over a fixed T

Comment: the bit that seems different is that the implicit converstion seems to want to apply a conversion based on a function type A=>B, but I want to implicitly apply forall T. A[T] => B[T] .....I think

Comment: @user2088029 if T is fixed, then `A[T] <: B[T]` iff A = B or A extends B. I think you need to reword your question to show a particular case you want to solve.

Comment: ?...I'm not a scala programmer, but if I were to use C# or F#, then "forall T. T[] <: IEnumerable[T]", arrays are subtypes of enumerables for a fixed T, any fixed T.

Comment: I'll remove the reference to "-","+" I think I'm misleading you